# Why a Integer Set container fill with String element

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I have a `Set`, it's generic type is Set. I get it from this code

```
Set<Integer> completeOrgTree = codeSetOfStores.stream().flatMap(item -> organizationDao.getUpstreamOrgByCode(item).stream()).collect(toSet());
```

the organizationDao.getUpstreamOrgByCode method is simple:

```
public Set<Integer> getUpstreamOrgByCode(String code){
    return organizationMapper.getUpstreamOrgByCode(code);
}
```

codeSetOfStores is a normal Set,i get it from

```
Set<String> codeSetOfStores = organizationDao.listOrganizations(OrganizationQuery.getInstance().storeIdList(new ArrayList<>(searchBean.getStoreIdSet())).fields("code").turnOffPage())
                        .stream().map(OrganizationEntity::getCode).collect(toSet());

//对于业务组织，获取关联该批分店的组织
Set<String> codeSetOfAssociatedStore = orgStoreAssociatedDao.listOrgStoreAssociated(OrgStoreAssociatedQuery.getInstance().turnOffPage().withStoreIdSet(searchBean.getStoreIdSet()).withFields("orgCode"))
                        .stream().map(OrgStoreAssociatedEntity::getOrgCode).collect(toSet());

//集合业务组织和非业务组织，查询该批组织及其上级
codeSetOfStores.addAll(codeSetOfAssociatedStore);
```

I have described the background of completeOrgTree above.

My problem is that when want to operate the completeOrgTree, I found that this container filled with String !!!

So every operation about this container will cause a ClassCastException,even what i do just print it

```
completeOrgTree.stream().forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

My JDK version is 1.8.0_131.

========================================================================

i found the answer.
what make this happen is the mybatis.
in the xml file , i have this methd

```
<select id="getUpstreamOrgByCode" resultType="String">
        SELECT
            id,
            `CODE`
        FROM
            t_org_architecture
        WHERE
            LEFT (#{code}, LENGTH(`CODE`)) = `CODE`;
    </select>
```

the resultType of this select is String.
int the java file , i have this corresponding method:

```
Set<Integer> getUpstreamOrgByCode(String code);
```

so,the mybatis put the string value into the set in spite of the type of this set is integer!!!

i guess mybatis do this by java reflection

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace of the ClassCastException you get

Comment: `System.out.println` wouldn't cast its parameter...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko No, but the lambda does. It's a `Consumer<Integer>`

Comment: @Michael whatever the stream contains, `.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item))` will suit it, where is `ClassCastException`?

Comment: What is `getUpstreamOrgByCode()` doing. It claims to return a Set of Integer, but have you verified that it really does that? When you dont find what you expect in your collection ... then better check what you put into it. The compiler can easily be tricked (or forced) to overlook "putting the wrong things" into a set.

Comment: So, from that point of view: please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: voting to close: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko See my answer. The cast is happening at `Consumer.accept`, one step before what you're talking about.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks,i will Compliance with the rules next time

Answer (score 3):

You are a victim of non-reified generics. At runtime, it is perfectly possible to put any object into a collection, regardless of its declared generic type. Generic types are not enforced at runtime.

Here is an example where I add 3 different types to a `List<Integer>`, which will also produce a class cast exception when you try to iterate over it.

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
List anyList = intList;
anyList.add(1);
anyList.add(new Object());
anyList.add("test");

intList.stream().forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

So I suppose whoever is responsible for populating the set has screwed up somewhere. You should ideally fix it at the source.

If that's not possible then cast it to a `Set<Object>` (since we know that that's *really* what it is, for whatever reason).

```
List<Object> objList = (List<Object>) (List) intList;
objList.stream().forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

If you want to do anything more complex than printing each item, you may need to check the type (`instanceof`) and then add some conditional logic for `String`s and `Integer`s.

Comment: The answer is as you said.And mybatis make this happen

Comment: @Zero.zheng Cool, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer.
what make this happen is the mybatis.
in the xml file , i have this methd

```
<select id="getUpstreamOrgByCode" resultType="String">
        SELECT
            id,
            `CODE`
        FROM
            t_org_architecture
        WHERE
            LEFT (#{code}, LENGTH(`CODE`)) = `CODE`;
    </select>
```

the resultType of this select is String.
int the java file , i have this corresponding method:

```
Set<Integer> getUpstreamOrgByCode(String code);
```

so,the mybatis put the string value into the set in spite of the type of this set is integer!!!

i guess mybatis do this by java reflection

Comment: See why your question is low-quality? No one would ever figure out you have an xml file and that a problem is there :)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko sorry,this is the first time i ask question here.i will Compliance with the rules next time.thank you

Comment: BTW, no need for reflection, just unchecked casts (and ignored warnings) can do that magic (see code in [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57287537/85421))

Comment: @Zero.zheng, It's OK, don't worry. Just make it better next time!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger that is not true
```
Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>();
        intSet.add("zero.zheng")//you can not compile this
```

Comment: where is the unchecked cast? (e.g. see discussion of **official** documentation of [checkedCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection(java.util.Collection,java.lang.Class))) or try `Set raw = new HashSet(); ... Set<Integer> set = (Set<Integer>) raw` - more details in Java Language Specification (e.g. [5.1.9. Unchecked Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9))

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger i mean i has declare Set<Integer> getUpstreamOrgByCode(String code),Inorder to fill it with string,mybatis should use reflection.

Comment: my comment was addressed to the last 2 lines of your answer: "*the mybatis **put the string value into the set** in spite of the type of this set is integer!!!

i guess mybatis do **this** by java reflection*"